# Not able to get the search text in lucene

Tags: lucene

I hereby paste the following code,

```
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
            import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
            import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
            import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField; 
            import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
            import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
            import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
            import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

            import java.io.*;
            import java.util.ArrayList;

            /**
             * This terminal application creates an Apache Lucene index in a folder and adds files into this index
             * based on the input of the user.
             */
            public class TextFileIndexer {
              private static StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
              private Analyzer anal = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);
              private IndexWriter writer;
              private ArrayList<File> queue = new ArrayList<File>();


              public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Enter the path where the index will be created: (e.g. /tmp/index or c:/temp/index)");

                String indexLocation = null;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String s = br.readLine();

                TextFileIndexer indexer = null;
                try {
                  indexLocation = s;
                  indexer = new TextFileIndexer(s);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                  System.out.println("Cannot create index..." + ex.getMessage());
                  System.exit(-1);
                }

                //===================================================
                //read input from user until he enters q for quit
                //===================================================
                while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                  try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the full path to add into the index (q=quit): (e.g. /home/ron/mydir or c:\\Users\\ron\\mydir)");
                    System.out.println("[Acceptable file types: .xml, .html, .html, .txt]");
                    s = br.readLine();
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                      break;
                    }

                    //try to add file into the index
                    indexer.indexFileOrDirectory(s);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error indexing " + s + " : " + e.getMessage());
                  }
                }

                //===================================================
                //after adding, we always have to call the
                //closeIndex, otherwise the index is not created    
                //===================================================
                indexer.closeIndex();

                //=========================================================
                // Now search
                //=========================================================
                IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLocation)));
                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
                TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5, true);

                s = "";
                while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                  try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the search query (q=quit):");
                    s = br.readLine();
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                      break;
                    }
                    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, "contents", analyzer).parse(s);
                    searcher.search(q, collector);
                    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

                    // 4. display results
                    System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
                    for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
                      int docId = hits[i].doc;
                      Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
                      System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("path") + " score=" + hits[i].score);
                    }

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error searching " + s + " : " + e.getMessage());
                  }
                }

              }

              /**
               * Constructor
               * @param indexDir the name of the folder in which the index should be created
               * @throws java.io.IOException when exception creating index.
               */
              TextFileIndexer(String indexDir) throws IOException {
                // the boolean true parameter means to create a new index everytime, 
                // potentially overwriting any existing files there.
                FSDirectory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));


                IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);

                writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);
              }

              /**
               * Indexes a file or directory
               * @param fileName the name of a text file or a folder we wish to add to the index
               * @throws java.io.IOException when exception
               */
              public void indexFileOrDirectory(String fileName) throws IOException {
                //===================================================
                //gets the list of files in a folder (if user has submitted
                //the name of a folder) or gets a single file name (is user
                //has submitted only the file name) 
                //===================================================
                addFiles(new File(fileName));

                int originalNumDocs = writer.numDocs();
                for (File f : queue) {
                  FileReader fr = null;
                  try {
                    Document doc = new Document();

                    //===================================================
                    // add contents of file
                    //===================================================
                    fr = new FileReader(f);

            //        doc.add(new TextField("contents", fr));
                    doc.add(new StringField("path", f.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
                    doc.add(new StringField("filename", f.getName(), Field.Store.YES));

                    writer.addDocument(doc);
                    System.out.println("Added: " + f);



                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    Field field = new StringField("contents", br.readLine().toString(),
                            Field.Store.YES);
                    doc.add(field);
                    writer.addDocument(doc);


                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not add: " + f);
                  } finally {
                    fr.close();
                  }
                }

                int newNumDocs = writer.numDocs();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("************************");
                System.out.println((newNumDocs - originalNumDocs) + " documents added.");
                System.out.println("************************");

                queue.clear();
              }

              private void addFiles(File file) {

                if (!file.exists()) {
                  System.out.println(file + " does not exist.");
                }
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                  for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                    addFiles(f);
                  }
                } else {
                  String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                  //===================================================
                  // Only index text files
                  //===================================================
                  if (filename.endsWith(".htm") || filename.endsWith(".html") || 
                          filename.endsWith(".xml") || filename.endsWith(".txt")  || filename.endsWith(".pdf") ) {
                    queue.add(file);
                  } else {
                    System.out.println("Skipped " + filename);
                  }
                }
              }

              /**
               * Close the index.
               * @throws java.io.IOException when exception closing
               */
              public void closeIndex() throws IOException {
                writer.close();
              }
            }
```

But when,I search for a particular string in the file. I get String Not Found.  The output is as follows,

```
Enter the path where the index will be created: (e.g. /tmp/index or c:/temp/index)
D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test/
Enter the full path to add into the index (q=quit): (e.g. /home/ron/mydir or c:\Users\ron\mydir)
[Acceptable file types: .xml, .html, .html, .txt]
D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Skipped segments.gen
Skipped segments_1
Skipped write.lock
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\demo.xml
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\exe.xml
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\Fruit.XML
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\Influence_People.pdf
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\new.html
Added fileName : D:/svn/phase2/JavaSource/test/test
Added: D:\svn\phase2\JavaSource\test\test\Toy.xml

************************
6 documents added.
************************
Enter the full path to add into the index (q=quit): (e.g. /home/ron/mydir or c:\Users\ron\mydir)
[Acceptable file types: .xml, .html, .html, .txt]
q
Enter the search query (q=quit):
for
Entered String is   :  for
fieldName =for
Found : 0 hits.
Enter the search query (q=quit):
i
Entered String is   :  i
Error searching i : this IndexReader is closed
Enter the search query (q=quit):
q
Entered String is   :  q
```

Answer (score 0):

"for" and "i" are both stopwords, by default, in `StandardAnalyzer`, and so can not eally be searched for.  The full list of default stop words is:

```
   "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
   "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
   "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
   "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
   "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
```

Seems likely there are other issues issues at work.  Don't know why your reader would be closed for the second query.  I don't know where the output "fieldName =for" is coming from either.  But hopefully that gets you started on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging your code in Luke? (Lucene Index Toolbox)
http://code.google.com/p/luke/

Luke is really nice in performing searches using different analyzers, inspecting the index storage, understanding how documents are scored based on searches etc.  It can help eliminate any problems with search code, since it directly works on the index files.

Luke works for both Java and .NET versions of Lucene.